# How to use join() in an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays with seperate stringS, and I want to combine them. I want to use the map function.

```
var names = [ ["Thomas", "Meeks"], 
                   ["Gregg", "Pollack"], 
                   ["Christine", "Wong"], 
                   ["Dan", "McGaw"] ];
var modifiedNames = names.map(function (array) {
          return array.join(" "); 
        }
);
```

This is not working, how can I use the join function in this context?

Comment: In what way does this not work? It works fine for me. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4prr/). What output are you expecting?

Comment: Works for me - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/RnwMB/)

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/3c8Nn/

Comment: Do you get a specific error? Works for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine on my end:

```
names.map(function(n){ return n.join(" "); });
```